# Is it possible to encrypt data AES ECB mode in Windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to encrypt data using `AES (ECB)` .How can i do it .I have tried `AES` class ,but it does not have an option to set the mode .Is there any other way available ? Any Windows phone `AES` libraries available which implement `ECB` mode of operation?

Thanks and Regards

Vaysage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: No or at least not with the standard `AesManaged` class.  Silverlight in all its current variants does not support the `Mode` property and always uses CBC.

Comment: Thanks sir . Is there any library available?

Comment: @Vaysage:  None that I know of.  Since Silverlight does contain a reasonable set of Cryptography functions there isn't a great demand for another library with more bells and whistles.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find a free library doing that.

In some projects I had to "fallback" to RijndaelManaged (block size set to 128).
It works well if you have to consume webservices in another language (AES + CBC + PKCS5Padding)

It doesn't help if you have a stict requirement for AES (ECB) :/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help .I got an implementation at [Simple_Cryptographer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Simple_Cryptographer.aspx).And I have ported it to work with byte arrays .

Answer (score 1):

There is [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) port for Silverlight, and it have what you need.
If you dont want to recomplilate it for Windows Phone for you own, you can take dll from this place: [Awkward Coder Blog](http://awkwardcoder.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-bouncy-castle-on-windows-phone-7.html)

Answer (score 0):

However you can. Use IV as zeros and encrypt block by block (16bytes/128bit), not a stream. Every block should have IV filled with zeros and it will mimic ECB.